# CCBezierTo easeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Working in Objective-c at the moment.

I am drawing a path for my sprite to follow and it all seems to be working fine but i just had one question that didnt seem to be answered anywhere.

My first two points in the Bezier are rather close together in relation to the third point and  when my sprite animates along this path it seems like it is being eased in to the animation with an abrupt stop at the end.

Is there a way to control this i'd like to have the animation be one consistent speed or possibly be eased out?

```
id bezierForward = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:totalDistance/300.f bezier:bezier];
[turkey runAction:bezierForward];
```

Comment: Have you tried out the various Ease actions? http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:actions_ease

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
id bezierForward = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:totalDistance/300.f bezier:bezier];
id easeBezierForward = [CCEaseOut actionWithAction:bezierForward rate:2.0]
[turkey runAction:easeBezierForward];
```

You will want to play with the rate value to see what ends up looking best to you.  You may have to try out some of the other `CCEaseOut` options like `CCEaseSineOut`

Link: [Cocos2d Ease Actions Guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_ease)

Answer (score 0):

Should probably be something like this, according to the docs:

```
id bezierForward = [CCEaseOut actionWithDuration:totalDistance/300.f bezier:bezier];
[turkey runAction:bezierForward];
```

As stated in the docs:

> **Variations**
>
> CCEaseIn: acceleration at the beginning
>
> CCEaseOut: acceleration at the end
>
> CCEaseInOut: acceleration at the beginning / end

Comment: There's no CCEaseOut creation method that takes a bezier as a parameter.